# Are there Delphi object serialization libraries with support for Generics?

Tags: xml, json, delphi, generics, serialization

All open source object serialization libraries which I know of (JvAppStorage, NativeXml, OmniXML, SuperObject, lkJSON) seem to have no support for Generics properties yet. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Do you know a library which has this feature or plans to add it? How about the JSON serialization library in Delphi 2010 (I am still using Delphi 2009)

Example

```
...
published
  property Prop1: TObjectList<TMyPersistent> read GetProp1 write SetProp1;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to my simple solution using **JCL/JVCL serializer** in this post:
[How to serialize Delphi TObjectList<TMyClass> type to XML with TJvAppXMLFileStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462029/how-to-serialize-delphi-tobjectlisttmyclass-type-to-xml-with-tjvappxmlfilestor/12526037#12526037)

Answer (score 2):

[DeHL](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=285) have for XML, ini but still not for JSON

Comment: The DeHL page says it is discontinued as of January 9, 2012

Answer (score 0):

SvSerializer is a Library that serializes and de-serializes to/from Objetic/JSON/XML. A complete tool!

https://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/wiki/SvSerializer